# java - accessing error info inside custom web.xml error pages

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, web.xml

I'm working on a java spring mvc project. I put this code in my `web.xml` to use custom error pages:

```
<error-page>
    <location>/error.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

Now, In case of any error(404, 400, ...) users see the `error.jsp` page instead of normal apache tomcat error page. My question is, **how can I access error info inside the error.jsp page?**
I want to use something like `${errorCode}` inside that jsp page.

Comment: You could call `<%response.getStatus();%>` to get the status of the response

Comment: `HttpServletResponse` does not have `getStatus()` method.

Comment: What Servlet API are you using? getStatus() method is a part of an interface from 3.0 version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the error comes from a servlet the exception details are passed as request attributes

```
     javax.servlet.error.status_code    java.lang.Integer
     javax.servlet.error.exception_type java.lang.Class
     javax.servlet.error.message        java.lang.String
     javax.servlet.error.exception      java.lang.Throwable
     javax.servlet.error.request_uri    java.lang.String
     javax.servlet.error.servlet_name   java.lang.String
```

You can show the error message like this

`<c:out value="${requestScope['javax.servlet.error.message']}"/>`